# Calculate value in textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have 6 textboxes. How to calculate the total of value entered by users. Users need to enter quantity in each textbox and then it will calculate with price that already display or show in label (quantity*price). The result will be showed in textbox **readonly**. Is it I need to use JavaScript? Can it be done by that?

```
            <h2> Product </h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th> Item </th>
    <th> Number </th>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> Quantity </th>
    <th> Price  </th>
    <th> Total</th>
  </tr>

       <tr>
                    <th> 1 </th>
                    <th> 485-3AB</th>
                    <th> Light ring </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox1" runat="server" class="form-input"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                    <th>  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="16.30"></asp:Label> </th>
                    <th>  <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal1" runat="server" class="form-input" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th> 2 </th>
                    <th> 985-BB</th>
                    <th> Charger </th>             
                    <th> <asp:TextBox  ID="txtbox2" runat="server" class="form-input"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                    <th> <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="6.50"></asp:Label> </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal2" runat="server" class="form-input" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th> 3 </th>
                    <th> 785-NM </th>
                    <th> Light Ring 3xl </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox  ID="txtbox3" runat="server" class="form-input"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                    <th>  <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="20.50"></asp:Label> </th>
                    <th>  <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal3" runat="server" class="form-input" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <th> 4 </th>
                    <th> M5-133 </th>
                    <th> Cable Type A </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox4" runat="server" class="form-input"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                    <th> <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="3.10"></asp:Label> </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" class="form-input" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th> 5 </th>
                    <th> M5-658 </th>
                    <th> Cable Type C </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox  ID="txtbox5" runat="server" class="form-input"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                    <th> <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="3.90"></asp:Label> </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" class="form-input" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th> 6 </th>
                    <th> 563-7A-8 </th>
                    <th> Tripod </th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox  ID="txtbox6" runat="server" class="form-input"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                    <th> <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="26.40"></asp:Label></th>
                    <th> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" class="form-input" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox> </th>
                </tr>
</table>

            <asp:Button ID="Submitbtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submitbtn_Click" />  
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so in what you are looking for 'javascript' or 'c#' ?

Comment: and you need to calculate in server side or client side itself?

Comment: in server side and i looking for method that easy to implement @Jeevan ebi

Answer (score 0):

you could use this for the button click code:

```
Protected Sub Submitbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    txtTotal1.Text = Nz(txtbox1.Text, 0) * Nz(Label1.Text, 0)
    txtTotal2.Text = Nz(txtbox2.Text, 0) * Nz(Label2.Text, 0)
    txtTotal3.Text = Nz(txtbox3.Text, 0) * Nz(Label3.Text, 0)
    TextBox4.Text = Nz(txtbox4.Text, 0) * Nz(Label4.Text, 0)
    TextBox5.Text = Nz(txtbox5.Text, 0) * Nz(Label5.Text, 0)
    TextBox6.Text = Nz(txtbox6.Text, 0) * Nz(Label6.Text, 0)



End Sub

Public Function Nz(ByVal Value As Object, Optional ByVal MyDefault As Object = "") As Object
    If Value Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Value) OrElse Value = "" Then
        Return MyDefault
    Else
        Return Value
    End If
End Function
```